# Best approach to validate each row in the database (performance concern)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a form that allows user to add multiple rows and when user type an input into each row I have to validate that the value is in the database.  For example, a user adding order number to each row and need to validate that the order number exist in the DB before adding another row.

It might me too costly to make a trip to the database each time the user add a row to the form.

What is a good way to approach this concern?

ASP.NET Core, MSSQL DB

Comment: The requirement is to "validate each row in the database".  So you must read back the value from the database unless the requirement changes.

Comment: Don't confuse "requirement" with "implementation". Typically one validates all values entered into any particular form/window in an application at the time the information is saved. Without context, it is difficult to make useful suggestion.

Comment: Foreign keys are typically used _to validate that the order number exist_.

Comment: "It might be too costly" - Have you measured? Is it super easy to guess incorrectly with regards to performance. So is useful to do representative measurements. I would expect a simple "does this key exist" to be fairly fast if using an index.

Comment: According to [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8) returns _The number of rows affected_ If you attempt to insert 5 rows, and ExecuteNonQuery returns that 5 rows were inserted, then one can assume that the data that you inserted into the database exists in the database. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: It's not clear how many simultaneous users you have. It should be apparent, there's a limit to how fast a human can input data which is affected by the types of control(s) used on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example of order number existent in the DB. Why don't you have a model populate with Order numbers and you can check in the Model for any previous data and if there isn't any you can add new data in the DB.

Comment: What if the  order tables contain million of rows, that might be too costly to pull all the rows in the DB at once